# How to Change value of textbox when a value selected in drop list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am just learning so please go easy on me.
I am using razor pages.
public class SalesModel : PageModel
{

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public SalesModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Sales Sale { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }


    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Customers = await _db.Customer.ToListAsync();
        Products = await _db.Product.ToListAsync();
    }
}

}
```

//This is View Page

```
<div class="col-6">
<select asp-for="Sale.Product_Name" id="Select1" class="form-control" required asp-items="@(new   SelectList(Model.Products, "Name", "Name"))">
<option value="" selected disabled>-- Select Product Name -- </option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
<input id="Rate" asp-for="Sale.Rate" class="form-control" required />
</div>
```

//I have populated Droplist with the values from DB but i tried and searched so much I am not being able to to set the value of a textbox according to the values selected in drop list

//Table View

```
ID  Name    Rate  Quantity
1   Biscuit 10    15
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected values will be bound to the property as passed in to the `asp-for` attribute, suitable type for capturing the selected value(s) - an `int`, `string` or `enum`. Or, if you permit multiple selections, a collection of any of these. You cannot bind to object

this wont work

```
[BindProperty]
    public Sales Sale { get; set; }
```

you can change the above code to something like below, and accordingly cshtml

```
[BindProperty]
    public string Product_Name{ get; set; }
```